# Using read to capture multiple variables from a command's output

Tags: command-line, bash, bash-scripting, youtube-dl, read

I have a `youtube-dl` command that when run outputs two new lines, and I'm trying to capture each of those to variables.

Here is what I have so far, but for some reason I can't understand, it only captures the first line of output while discarding the second (`$audio` is empty).

```
read -r video audio <<< "$(youtube-dl -g --youtube-skip-dash-manifest https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-gcvAxJJiGo)"
```

How can I fix it to make it capture both inputs, or alternatively, is there a more reliable way to do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`read -r video audio` will capture the first ($IFS separated) **word** into "video" and the **rest of the line** into "audio"

Another way to capture 2 lines is with command grouping and a process substitution:

```bsh
{
  read -r video
  read -r audio
} < <(
  youtube-dl -g --youtube-skip-dash-manifest "$url"
)
```

The space between `< <(` is important: a `<(process substitution)` acts like a file, so you're using `<` to redirect input from a file.

---

It just occurred to me: another way to read *lines of output* is the [`mapfile`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-mapfile) command:

```bsh
mapfile -t lines < <(youtube-dl ...)
declare -p lines  # just to inspect the array contents

video=${lines[0]}
audio=${lines[1]}
```

Comment: Accepted because although it's still more complicated a solution than I would have hoped for, this seems to be the simplest performant solution so far.

Answer (score 3):

[`read` reads one line by design](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/328783/108618). The simplest way to read two lines is to use `read` twice.

```bsh
exec 3< <(youtube-dl -g --youtube-skip-dash-manifest 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-gcvAxJJiGo')
IFS= read -r -u3 video
IFS= read -r -u3 audio
exec 3>&-
```

`read -u` is not portable, [neither is `<(…)`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/309547/108618). They work in Bash and your question is tagged [bash](/questions/tagged/bash), so they should work for you.

Note I single-quoted the string containing `?` in case you had a directory `https:/www.youtube.com/` and a matching file therein. It's only remotely possible, still quoting wildcard characters that should not be treated as wildcards is good practice in any shell. Compare [what happens in Zsh](https://superuser.com/a/1551937/432690).

Empty `IFS` [is the right thing in general](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/209184/108618), when you want to read a line.

[This other answer](https://superuser.com/a/1660859/432690) does not use `exec` and it's good. It's my *personal preference* to set input up visually before tools that will use it (compare [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1335355/432690)). Unfortunately `<(…) { …; }` does not work. With `exec` I can do it.

Or I can do it by piping `youtube-dl` to the rest of the script.

```sh
youtube-dl -g --youtube-skip-dash-manifest 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-gcvAxJJiGo' \
| {
IFS= read -r video
IFS= read -r audio
}
```

Normally Bash runs the `{ … }` fragment in a subshell, so the variables will not survive after `}`. `shopt -s lastpipe` can change this (if job control is not active). Without `lastpipe` (which is not portable) the entire approach is portable but you need to run everything that uses the variables inside the `{ }` block because you don't know if it's a subshell or not (POSIX allows both behaviors). Note the stdin inside the block comes from `youtube-dl`; if anything inside the block needs to use the stdin of the entire script then you may need to use `exec` anyway to juggle the descriptors.

Another portable approach is like this:

```sh
input="$(youtube-dl -g --youtube-skip-dash-manifest 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-gcvAxJJiGo')"
video="$(printf '%s\n' "$input" | head -n 1)"
audio="$(printf '%s\n' "$input" | head -n 2 | tail -n 1)"
```

Instead of `head` and `tail` you can use `sed` or `awk` to isolate the right line.

Note this solution does not use `read`. If you need features of `read` then this is not the way. It seems you don't need the features of `read` in this particular case though.

Even if `youtube-dl` was very fast, I would not advise `video="$(youtube-dl … | head -n 1)"` plus `audio="$(youtube-dl … | …)"`. If `video` and `audio` come from the same `input`, from the same invocation of `youtube-dl`, then they are as coherent as the tool allows. Otherwise they may be incoherent. Frankly I don't know how incoherent they may be (if ever); but I know in general it's better to query once (e.g. `date +%H:+%M` should always be coherent; `date +%H; date +%M` will surprise you if you run it just before a full hour).